# Keep app open and logged in between test scenarios

Tags: javascript, cucumberjs

I am writing tests in Java Script for a native app using appium and cucumber. The app design is as follows.

Login through a 3rd party (salesforce) login screen, sync data down from salesforce to the application then test the application.

Because this login and sync step can take a long time to complete I would like to be able to have the system login, then run all the tests on an already logged in application, then tear the app down only once all my behave tests have finished.

Is there a way of keeping the same instance of the application up between test scenarios?